# Foreign Key field is not registering in Database

Tags: django, model, field

I add a new foreign key in my model but it gives an error once I migrate.

Field 'id' expected a number but got 'XD'.

MODEL:

```
item_tool= models.ForeignKey(Tools,default='XD', on_delete=SET_DEFAULT)
```

CLASS:

```
class Tools(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tools'

    def __str__(self):
        

        return self.name
```

CATEGORIES

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        

        return self.name
```

MODEL:

```
 item_category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, default='Coding', on_delete=SET_DEFAULT)
```

Comment: You can not set `default='XD'`, since the `ForeignKey` expects or a `Tools` object, or the primary key of the model to refer to.

Answer (score 1):

You can not set `default='XD'`, since the `ForeignKey` expects or a `Tools` object, or the primary key of the model to refer to.

What you can do however is pass a reference to a callable that will retrieve or create a `Tools` object with the name `'XD'`:

```
def xd_tool():
    return Tools.objects.get_or_create(name='XD')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    item_tool = models.ForeignKey(Tools, default=xd_tool, on_delete=SET_DEFAULT)
```

We can boost efficiency by caching the `XD` tool in the function, you can only do this if tools do *not* change their at some point in time:

```
def xd_tool():
    cache = getattr(xd_tool, 'cache', None)
    if cache is not None:
        return cache
    xd_tool.cache = cache = Tools.objects.get_or_create(name='XD')
    return cache
```

I would also advise to make the names of your `Tools` model unique, otherwise there can be two tools with the same name introducing a lot of confusion:

```
class Tools(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tools'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Tool` instead of <s>`Tools`</s>.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I am new user and earlier in my model i made a simple category field and it works fine . this time i try to dublicate the same process but now getting error.

Comment: @Waqart: you should also define a function for categories, and use `default=that_function` to automatically set it to a `Categories` object.